# Matrix column dimension containing '>' in C

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, c

I found a small C function that given a matrix, it removes the line 0 and the column 'i' and then put it in another matrix,

everything in order to calculate the determinant of the simplified matrix , but I have not ever seen a matrix column size like this:

```
void togli_riga0_colonnai(double mat [][dim], int n, int i, double matreduced[][dim]) 
 {
   int j, l;
  for(j=1;j<n;j++) {
    for(l=0;l<n;l++) {
      if(l!=i)
    matreduced[j-1][l-(l>i)]=mat[j][l];     
    }  
  }
}
```

**within the '>' sign.**
Can anyone tell me what it could mean and when is it used?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It's just a greater-than sign.  The resulting expression returns a boolean value.  In C, boolean values are defined as `true == 1` and `false == 0`.  So this just looks like a bit of tricky math, equivalent to

```
matreduced[j-1][l-1]
```

if `l` is greater than `i`, and

```
matreduced[j-1][l]
```

if it isn't.